# Google Cloud Console dosen't show project information

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I use GCP (VM Instance) by myself (not a team).
Google Cloud Console hasn't shown my project information since few days ago.
When I click "VM Instance", "Snapshot", "IAM" ,"Billing" or "support", nothing is shown.

["VM Instance" capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA3Gr.png)

I tried clearing the browser cache, another browser. but this hasn't fixed.
Please let me know what should I do, or where to contact GCP support.
(GCP support page tells that I should contact by "support" link.
But "Support" link doesn't show anything, either.)

---

I Opened the browser debugger and refresh the page.
there are some errors in the console.

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIMJL.png)

It says that it's because of 'Unknown' script.
I don't know why that happens.

Comment: Open the browser debugger. Refresh the page. Are there errors reported in the Console or Network tab?

Comment: try to use a new-incognito or private browser, or try to switch ISP.

Comment: Thanks John. I tried in browser debugger and refresh the page. the browser (chrome) showed my project data once or twice, then reverted. I added error message on my question.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. I tried using a private browser, but it didn't work.

Comment: Go thru the normal procedure of disabling browser add-ons, clearing browser cache, restarting the computer, etc. The problem is most likely with your system.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
This was because of Antivirus Software.
Thanks for your advice.